# How can I measure the time taken to transition from one screen to another in swift xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am building an app that requires me to measure the time taken to measure the time taken from when the user initiated a request that would show the screen to the point where the screen has finished drawing.
say for instance I have 2 view controller V1 and V2. I want to be able to measure how long it takes for the page to display the data of V2 from the point when the user initiate the action from V1 and vice-versa.

I have tried putting a code that start timer in viewdidload and stop when viewdidappear but it doesn't feel right. perhaps there is a method in app delegate that can do this ? I am not sure.

Comment: you probably want a timer to start in VC1's viewWillDisappear and end in VC2's viewDidAppear